# Inkscape (and Cricut Design Space): Text problems

Tags: inkscape, text, svg

I've imported an svg to edit in Inkscape, creating this text with lines, selected all and converted stroke to path. I may have also clicked Object to Path at some point and admittedly am not really sure if that has done anything or not.

But the design is now looking like this, with some lines bold and others thin (the red screenshot). When uploading into Cricut Design Space (black and green screenshot) to cut the svg, the thin lined letters show to cut as I wanted (although strangely doesn't show colour), but the bold lined letters are set to cut as an outline (which I do not want).

I'm only new to Inkscape and trying to figure things out, but completely lost on what to do here. Hoping someone has some ideas. Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you share the original SVG you imported?  How was it made?  In Inkscape, or in other software?  It's hard to tell what's going on here without access to the original SVG, to see how it was constructed.  If it was me, I'd just recreate it entirely in Inkscape from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

It might have been the "object to path" after you converted your text to a path. What you ended up with was your stroke being outlined into a shape, instead of a single-line path, on the bold letters.

Have you tried recreating the text and converting it to a path from scratch? That will probably be the easiest way to fix this.

If you don't have the font used for your image, this one from Kimberly Geswein should work (free for personal use): https://www.dafont.com/kg-primary-penmanship.font